# Can I connect Solution Explorer in SSMS to Azure DevOps like you do in Visual Studio?

Tags: ssms

I manage a few on-premise SQL Servers with SSMS, have been doing so for a while.  Back in the day, I setup a local git repository to store all my scripts in, and this worked great for just me.

Times change and with more team members and more servers, I have since uploaded all my scripts to my company's Azure DevOps instance, which was 100% painless.  When I started using SSIS/Visual Studio, I stored the projects in Azure DevOps to start, and that worked out.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get **SSMS to use Azure DevOps for a solution location**.  Is there a plugin I'm missing?  Google searches for it don't seem to turn anything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS is or was under the hood Visual Studio, but the took another path years ago. So unfortunately no Azure DevOps integration out of the box there.

There are however a number of vendors creating solutions as plugin or stand alone tool to support your process:

**Plugins**

- [Redgate SQL Source control](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/)
- [Alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/sql-source-control/)

**Stand alone, side-by-side or replacing SSMS**

- [Flyway Desktop](https://flywaydb.org/blog/introducing-flyway-desktop-in-community)
- [Visual studio with SSDT](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/12/comparison-review-microsoft-ssdt-vs-red-gate-sql-source-control/)
- [Azure Data Studio with plugins](https://www.sqlshack.com/source-control-using-git-in-azure-data-studio-ads/)

There is a lot out there, please be sure to look at your work [process first](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/redgate-deploy/a-real-world-implementation-of-database-devops-people-processes-tools) before choosing a tool.